# Create script in SQL Server 2008 which is compatible with SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have a Database in SQL Server 2008 and i want to create the complete database script which is compatible with SQL Server 2000. All the datatypes that I've used are compatible with SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Easier to go the other way. Do the the script in 2000, it will almost certainly be OK in 2008. More a question of not making use of new features, than old fetaures no longer there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what you'd do for SQL Server 2000 compatability:

1. Right-click on your database, **Tasks** -> **Generate Scripts...**
2. Choose your entire database
3. In *Set Scripting Options* click the **Advanced** button
4. There is an option for ***Script for Server Version***
5. Select the drop down option for **SQL Server 2000**